# idea Vim plugin integration in phpstorm

Tags: git, phpstorm, ideavim

After installing `idea Vim plugin` to use `GIT`, I am facing some peculiar problem right now.
Every time when i select some text in `phpstorm` with mouse, using `backspace` to delete the selected text  it doesn't delete the text but it mark the text untill  i stop pressing backspace. 
But the backspace work everywhere.

Is this problem occur because of installing the plugin?

Is this problem solvable without uninstalling the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the VIM plugin you have VIM commands. So use them that is the sin of that plugin.

I've tried that plugin some times ago but it was not working very well it's changing all key commands.